# Skipping error message while using tcl for loop for creating multiple components

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, tcl

I am newbie at TCL. Sorry for simple question. I want to create entities with using TCL.

if there is any component in my range, i want to skip it and incr i 1 step forward.

For example, i created comp pshell.15, this code works until 15 and exit with error.

Please help me for skipping this error.

Regards

```
for {set i 10} {$i <20} {incr i} {

 *createentity comps name=pshell.$i id=$i
 puts $i
            if { [catch {*?????? }] } {
                incr i 
                continue
                

}
}
```

Comment: Are the `*` characters in your input, or are they an attempt to highlight things? (The code highlighter doesn't respect them at all.) I ask because it's not a common character in command names. Also… **what does the error message say?** Tcl's error messages are usually very good at describing the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, assuming that `*createentity comps name=pshell.$i id=$i` command is correct (whatever it is, I really don't know!), to skip error messages in case of failure you should use `try`. This will not skip the command however, this just allows you to handle it gracefully.

There's no need to `incr i` before `continue`.

```
for {set i 10} {$i < 20} {incr i} {
  try {
    *createentity comps name=pshell.$i id=$i
  } on error {} {
    continue
  }
  puts $i
}
```